# Associate dynamic text to a label

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, links

I'm trying to associate some text (dynamically generated with counters) to a label, so that I can refer to that label and print the text associated(without re-generating it, that would cause problems with counters).

Example of usage:

```
\textLabel{key}{\dynamicText}
```

Somewhere, after, in the document i want to have a new macro that links to key and displays the text generated by \dynamictext.

This macro does not quite work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textLabel}[2]{%
    \protected@edef\var{\expandafter\noexpand#2}%
    \label{#1}\var%
    \global\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\hyperref[#1]{\var}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The macro `\var` seems to work just fine.
The problem is that the macro identified with `\#1` is nor visible in the document, and produces an error (control sequence not found).

Where am I goingwrong?

---

Context:
I have a long list of items that need an unique ID in some strange format. 
I'm automatically generating the ID for the items in the list, with a call to a macro that increases some counters and returns the IDs in function of the values of the counters.

Now, I want to write the IDs generated and refer to the items, without the need of recall the macro used to build them. (It would mean to call the `\getID` in the same order and number of times, and I don't want it)

---

Here a minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}       

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textLabel}[2]{%
    \protected@edef\var{\expandafter\noexpand#2}%
    \label{#1}\var%
    \global\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\hyperref[#1]{\var}}
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{req}
\newcommand{\getid}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{req}%
    #1.\arabic{req}%
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeyone}{\getid{ITEM}}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeytwo}{\getid{ITEM}}
    \end{itemize}

    \itemkeyone %I want: ITEM.1, instead produces command not found
\end{document}
```

Here a minimal working example, but with the wrong behaviour:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}       

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\textLabel}[2]{%
    \label{#1}#2%
    \global\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\hyperref[#1]{#2}}
}


\newcounter{req}
\newcommand{\getid}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{req}%
    #1.\arabic{req}%
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeyone}{\getid{ITEM}}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeytwo}{\getid{ITEM}}
    \end{itemize}

    \itemkeyone %I want: ITEM.1, instead produces ITEM.3
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: The reason why it prints `item.3` is that `\getId` isn't expandable and does not have the value of the counter at the time of definition, but at the time of calling `\itemkeyone` (plus +1, since it's stepped then)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a completely different approach using [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). With all of the comments the code is longer than Manuel's so pehaps I can't claim simplicity, but I just like using pgfkeys for things like this.

To show that it works here's what my code produces:
[image]
...and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/MyLabels/.is family, /MyLabels,
  % set labels using \pgfkeyssetvalue => can test with \pgfkeysifdefined
  % This allows arbitrary new keys to be defined on the fly
  .unknown/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/MyLabels/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}},
}

\newcounter{getID}% a dummy counter to imitate \getID

\newcommand\SetLabel[1]{% set label to current value of getID
  \stepcounter{getID}% might want \refstepcounter in real life
  Settting: #1 = ID\arabic{getID} %
  \pgfkeys{/MyLabels,#1/.expanded=ID\arabic{getID}}% force expansion
  (stored value: \pgfkeys{/MyLabels/#1}).
}
\newcommand\UseLabel[1]{% print label if it bas been defined
  Getting: #1 =
   \pgfkeysifdefined{/MyLabels/#1}%
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/MyLabels/#1}}% print if defined
      {???}% question marks if not defined
  .%
}

\begin{document}

\SetLabel{first}

\SetLabel{second}

\UseLabel{first}

\UseLabel{second}

\UseLabel{first}

\end{document}
```

**Edit: Solution II**

I realised that this is all overkill: you should just be using LaTeX's `\label` and `\ref` commands. When you create a label what happens is that the current value of `\@currentlabel` is written to the aux file and this is then accessible on the next compile using `\ref`. So if you set `\@currentlabel` to the output of `\getID` then you are done. You can't, however, set `\@currentlabel` equal to `\getID{item}` because the `\getID` command contains some unexpandable stuff. Instead you should make `\getID` set a dummy variable or, better still, set `\@currentlabel`.

Here is a second solution based on your MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\newcommand\textLabel[2]{\getid{#2}\label{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{req}
\newcommand{\getid}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{req}%
    \def\@currentlabel{#1.\arabic{req}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeyone}{ITEM}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeytwo}{ITEM}
    \end{itemize}

    \ref{itemkeyone} %I want: ITEM.1

    \ref{itemkeytwo} %I want: ITEM.1
\end{document}
```

As this is using `\label` and `\ref` behind the scenes the labels will persist from one compile to the next but you will need to compile the document twice before it takes effect.

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I'm going wih the solution II.
It works perfectly, even using some other macro to get the formatted ID :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nopaste Glad it was helpful! I just edited Solution II to make it a little nicer: you shouldn't call `\getid` inside the `\texLabel` command. Rather, `\textLabel` should be given the "label" and then call `\getid` with it.

Answer (score 2):

A style with writing `textlabels` as faked labels to the `.aux` file, manually establishing the `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` then.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}       

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcounter{req}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textLabel}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{req}%
  \hypertarget{#1.\number\value{req}}{#2.\arabic{req}}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{#1.\number\value{req}}{{#2.\number\value{req}}{}{}{}{}} % Write the text label!
  }
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded{\hyperlink}{#1.\number\value{req}}{\getrefnumber{#1.\number\value{req}}}
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo} \label{foolabel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textLabel{itemkeyone}{ITEM}
          \clearpage
        \item \textLabel{itemkeytwo}{ITEM}
    \end{itemize}

\clearpage
    \itemkeyone %I want: ITEM.1, instead produces ITEM.3

    \itemkeytwo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this works, but haven't tested thoroughly

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{req}
\newcommand*\getid[1]{\def\thereq{#1.\arabic{req}}\refstepcounter{req}\thereq} 

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \getid{ITEM} \label{itemkeyone}
  \item \getid{ITEM} \label{itemkeytwo}
\end{itemize}
\ref{itemkeyone}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It seems to work fine, (I'm not able to understand how it works, however)

But there is some problem, maybe I semplified the problem too much. If I try to add a link with: `\hyperref[test]{\getid{ITEM}}  \label{itemkeyone}` it doesn't work anymore.

That list is a list of names of items, each item should be link with it's definition (in some part of the document), and from the definition I should be able to go to the list...

edit. It works if I put the label inside the hyperref

Comment: It is normal that I'm not able to replace `#1.\arabic{req}` with a macro? (the macro that really generates the id)

Comment: @Nopaste It depends what is inside the macro. One alternative is to have the macro set a dummy variable, which will be expandable, and then use that.